# Does input split get copied to JobTracker FileSystem?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As mentioned in Hadoop definitive guide, during submission of an MR job, Input splits get computed and then, get copied to JobTracker's FileSystem. However, it does not make sense to me if the data is really huge. This copy will take a lot of time and also, if the node running JobTracker does not have enough space, what would happen to this copy? Please clarify this processing framework.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InputSplits are just a logical abstraction of block boundaries. Generally a [InputSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileSplit.html) contains the following information:

- Path to the file
- Block start position
- Number of bytes in the file to process
- List of hosts containing the blocks for file being processed

For a given job its the responsibility of the [JobClient](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html) to compute the input splits information (which is just an ArrayList of above stated `FileSplit` objects) by calling `writeSplits` method which internally calls the `InputFormat`'s `getSplits` method, once computed this information is copied to HDFS from where the JobTracker will read and will schedule the mappers based on data-locality.

If you are interested in how the splits themselves are calculated take a look at the *[FileInputFormat.getSplits](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/HDFS-641/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#L245)* method.